# How to inject constructor parameters into an interface binding?

Tags: c++, boost, dependency-injection

I am trying to pass constructor parameters (https://boost-ext.github.io/di/examples.html#binding-to-constructor) along with the binding but keep getting errors, here is my demo:

[Wandbox Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/czzkvcLz3AwPXQJA)

```
#include <boost/di.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace di = boost::di;

int main() {
   
        typedef int64_t Type;
        class IS {
        public:
            virtual ~IS() = default;
            virtual Type doSomething() = 0;
        };
        class S : public IS {
            Type i_;
        public:
            S(Type i) : i_(i){}
            virtual Type doSomething() {
               return i_;
            }
        };
        const auto injector = boost::di::make_injector(
                boost::di::bind<IS>().to<S>()(10)
        );

        auto test = injector.create<std::unique_ptr<IS>>();
        std::cout << test->doSomething() << std::endl;
}
```

Errors and warnings:

```
warning C4996: 'boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::injector<TConfig,boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::pool<boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::aux::type_list<>>,dependency>::create': creatable constraint not satisfied
        with
        [
            TConfig=boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::config
        ]

note: see reference to function template instantiation 'T boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::create<std::unique_ptr<BoostDependencyInjectionTestSuite::ContructorParameterTest::test_method::IS,std::default_delete<BoostDependencyInjectionTestSuite::ContructorParameterTest::test_method::IS>>,boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::injector<TConfig,boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::pool<boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::aux::type_list<>>,dependency>>(const TInjector &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=std::unique_ptr<BoostDependencyInjectionTestSuite::ContructorParameterTest::test_method::IS,std::default_delete<BoostDependencyInjectionTestSuite::ContructorParameterTest::test_method::IS>>,
            TConfig=boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::config,
            TInjector=boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::injector<boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::config,boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::core::pool<boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::aux::type_list<>>,dependency>
        ]

warning C4506: no definition for inline function 'T
*boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::concepts::abstract_type<T>::is_not_bound::error(boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::_)'
        with
        [
            T=BoostDependencyInjectionTestSuite::ContructorParameterTest::test_method::IS
        ]

warning C5046: 'boost::ext::di::v1_2_0::concepts::abstract_type<T>::is_not_bound::error': Symbol involving type with internal linkage not defined
        with
        [
            T=BoostDependencyInjectionTestSuite::ContructorParameterTest::test_method::IS
        ]
```

Comment: What are the errors? (Copy-paste the text of the error message.)

Comment: The errors are shown within the wandbox demo.

Comment: *"within the wandbox demo"* is not an excuse. You might want to review the [help/on-topic] (*"Questions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?') must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."*) and [ask] (*"The first paragraph in your question is the second thing most readers will see, so make it as engaging and informative as possible."*).